# Difference between PQCs and VQCs

Tags: quantum-algorithms, variational-quantum-algorithms

I'm going through this TensorFlow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/quantum_reinforcement_learning) on quantum machine learning.  The code implements reinforcement learning algorithms based on parameterized/variational quantum circuits (PQCs or VQCs).

What is the difference between PQC and VQC?  Are they equivalent or are there subtle differences between them?  I'm trying to find literature that discusses this.